Old movie where a guy goes underground into an alien city
There’s this movie I’ve been trying to find for over a decade.
All I remember is him and this girl go underground, and there’s this wall that they stick their hand through and on the other side is a hidden city. I think it was a city of aliens or creatures.
It had to have been from the late 90s or early 2000s? Think I watched reruns of it on Fox as a kid, but I can’t remember.

Can you tell us a bit more about what the protagonists or the aliens/creatures looked like? Also, when you say they stuck their hand through a wall, did you mean a hole in the wall, or did their hand pass through the wall like it was an illusion or something?

Your description reminds me a little bit of Beneath the Planet of the Apes (1970), but it's older than you suggested, and you didn't mention any talking apes.

They looked like teens or in their twenties. One was a guy with brown hair, and the other was a girl and I think she had short red hair. The wall was like an illusion where they could stick their hand through it and realized it could go through it. They went underground in a sewage or something, and that’s where the wall was that they could pass through to the other side into this city.

What was on that another side?

Reminds me a bit of Phantasm

A city is on the other side. Almost like a small town with carts and being walking through. The movie had to take place in a New York or something, because I remember taxis being above the sewage location. Then they would go into the sewage underground, find that wall, stick there hand through it and enter the other side
